# How to call a contract's balanceOf function for a specific block using Web3.py

Tags: python-3.x, web3py

How can I get the balance of a token at a specific time? I'm using Web3.py. Nothing I seem to try works. I can get the latest balance of [USDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USD_Coin) for a particular wallet like this:

```
contract = web3.eth.contract('0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48', abi=self.ABI)

raw_balance = contract.functions.balanceOf('0xAb5801a7D398351b8bE11C439e05C5B3259aeC9B').call()
```

I try to specify the block number inside of the `call()` function:

```
raw_balance = contract.functions.balanceOf(wallet_address).call(block_identifier=13372637)
```

But I get an error each time:

> requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing

```
contract.functions.<function>.call(block_identifier=web3.eth.get_block('latest')['number'])
```

If that works using the latest block, then you might need to pay extra to get historical data, unfortunately...

EDIT:
Another possibility is you're using `np.int64` or another `int` variant. Try enforcing `int(block_no)` and see if that works

EDIT EDIT:
Also, try using https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/ instead of Infura. Free account worked for me..